# Adobe Flex 4.5 "Hero" for mobile - pros and cons

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, air, cross-platform, flex4.5

currently i am in a process of gathering information about cross-platform mobile development using Flex 4.5 framework (code name “Hero”). I am sure, these days lots of developers are interested in this topic.

For those of you who have experience with Flex 4.5 or higher, what pros and cons.

- Which hardware APIs can or cannot be accessed with flex? Are these the only native extensions available right now? http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html (i'd love to see a table with a sum up of what's )
- Native UI widgets is there any way to use native widgets (access them rather than fake them)? (ie iOS datepicker?)
- Performance - from what i read and saw in demos performance is very good... do you have negative experience?

In general, what are the most important limitations that discouraged you from using Flex 4.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con: Adobe has abandoned Flash player for mobile devices recently. Will it do the same for the Flex/AIR?

Comment: not exactly the answer i expected but its the best answer i got :)

Comment: Stackoverflow is still a very cool place for asking Flex questions - much better than the flexcoders mailing list (dead?) and Adobe forums (lame).

Comment: You personally consider Flex viable for future mobile development?

Comment: Yes, because it is just a hobby for me - have 1 small card game :-)